# Why to use secondary index (`on`) in data.table, unless for joining?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm a big fan of `data.table`, but have this confusion about use of `on`

Is this

```
A) flights["JFK", on = "origin"]
```

not the same as

```
B) flights["JFK" == origin]; # Or  flights["JFK" == get("origin")];
```

?

What would be the reason to use the former (A) instead of latter (B) ? In other words, if anyone can use dt[this == "that"], what was the reason to introduce another way of doing exactly the same with dt["that" , on = "this"]?
Can't see the reason for this from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html).

PS. I do understand why `on` was introduced  for merging files (like it in `dtA[dtB, on=.(A2=B2)]`). I used all the time and love it - as it makes the code so much shorter and easier to read, and is also very fast!

Answer (score 4):

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has a lot of optimizations. And interestingly, if you switched the order to `flights[origin == "JFK"]` then [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) will create an index when there are enough rows. Here are some options using `verbose = TRUE` to help see what is happening:

```r
library(data.table)
flights <- fread("vignettes/flights14.csv")

## Using binary merge method explicitly
invisible(flights["JFK", on = "origin", verbose = TRUE])

## i.V1 has same type (character) as x.origin. No coercion needed.
## forder.c received 253316 rows and 11 columns
## Calculated ad hoc index in 0.010s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
## Starting bmerge ...
## forder.c received 1 rows and 1 columns
## bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
## Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 



## No optimization. Very quiet
invisible(flights["JFK" == origin, verbose = TRUE])



## Note an index is created and the message is similar to the first option
invisible(flights[origin == "JFK", verbose = TRUE])
## Creating new index 'origin'
## Creating index origin done in ... forder.c received 253316 rows and 11 columns
## forder took 0.09 sec
## 0.500s elapsed (0.570s cpu) 
## Optimized subsetting with index 'origin'
## forder.c received 1 rows and 1 columns
## forder took 0 sec
## x is already ordered by these columns, no need to call reorder
## i.origin has same type (character) as x.origin. No coercion needed.
## on= matches existing index, using index
## Starting bmerge ...
## bmerge done in 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
## Constructing irows for '!byjoin || nqbyjoin' ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu)
```

So to your question, why do the `on =`  join method? It will use binary merge to efficiently find matches and subset which can be super fast when there is an existing index. Additionally, `on =`  will not create an index automatically which may be desirable.

Related, `dt["a", on = "ID"]` gets translated into `dt[data.table(V1 = "a"), on = "ID"]` with additional processing to help with the names. In other words, it is just user convenience to the more common `dtA[dtB, on=.(A2=B2)]` that you are a fan of.

Why would you use `dt[this == "that"]` is that the code is very straight forward - anyone in R would recognize what is happening. Additionally, for larger data.tables a new index would automatically be created which may be desirable. This is probably the code I would move forward with.

Comment: I see you edited your post. I feel like the paragraphs after the code block address your edit. Also, if it helps, [tag:data.tablle] is 14 years old. The ```dt[that = "this"]``` being able to self-optimize to use indices is only a recent introduction of the last few years. Plus, as I indicated, the ```on``` syntax is mainly user convenience for a typical join statement with another ```data.table```.